# Resized Image Taken by iOS Camera Does Not Show Up As Same After Shot

Tags: ios, swift, camera

My problem is that after the image is shot, it scales itself thus it does not seem exactly the same view what I would expect by looking at the camera view.

To handle camera work, I am using open source library, a pod, which is called CameraManager. You can find my code below, later I will explain how the image scales itself.

```
import UIKit
import CameraManager

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var height: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var width: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!

    let cameraManager = CameraManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView.hidden = true

        height.constant = self.view.frame.width
        width.constant = self.view.frame.width

        imageHeight.constant = self.view.frame.width
        imageWidth.constant = self.view.frame.width

        cameraManager.addPreviewLayerToView(self.cameraView)
        cameraManager.writeFilesToPhoneLibrary = false
    }

    @IBAction func shootImage(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("bastim")
        print("self.imageView.frame.height \(self.cameraView.frame.height) and self.imageView.frame.width \(self.cameraView.frame.width)")
        print("camera x \(self.cameraView.frame.origin.x) and camera y \(self.cameraView.frame.origin.y)")

        cameraManager.capturePictureWithCompletition({ (image, error) -> Void in
            var ratio: CGFloat
            var delta: CGFloat
            var offset: CGPoint

            let size: CGSize = CGSizeMake(self.cameraView.frame.width, self.cameraView.frame.height)

            if(image?.size.width > image?.size.height) {
                ratio = self.cameraView.frame.width / image!.size.width
                delta = ratio*image!.size.width - ratio*image!.size.height
                offset = CGPointMake(delta/2, 0)
            }else {
                ratio = self.cameraView.frame.width / image!.size.height
                delta = ratio*image!.size.height - ratio*image!.size.width
                offset = CGPointMake(0, delta/2)
            }
            print("delta \(delta)")

            let clipRect: CGRect = CGRectMake(-offset.x, -offset.y, (ratio * image!.size.width) + delta, (ratio * image!.size.height) + delta)

            if (UIScreen.mainScreen().respondsToSelector(Selector("scale")) && UIScreen.mainScreen().scale >= 2.0) {
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0.0)
            }else {
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
            }

            UIRectClip(clipRect)
            image?.drawInRect(clipRect)
            let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            self.cameraView.hidden = true
            self.imageView.hidden = false
            self.imageView.image = newImage
        })
    }

    @IBAction func repeatProcess(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.cameraView.hidden = false
        self.imageView.hidden = true
    }

}
```

Below you can find my problem in detail.

It may scale wrong or it may cropping the wrong size. I am not sure which of two is correct. To be honest, I am a bit lost and cannot find the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer! Those who confront with the same problem, please refer to the code below. This worked great for me:

```
 @IBAction func shootImage(sender: AnyObject) {

    print("self.cameraView.frame.height \(self.cameraView.frame.height) and self.cameraView.frame.width \(self.cameraView.frame.width)")
    print("camera x \(self.cameraView.frame.origin.x) and camera y \(self.cameraView.frame.origin.y)")

    print("self.imageView.frame.height \(self.imageView.frame.height) and self.imageView.frame.width \(self.imageView.frame.width)")
    print("image view x \(self.imageView.frame.origin.x) and image view y \(self.imageView.frame.origin.y)")


    cameraManager.capturePictureWithCompletition({ (image, error) -> Void in
        let scaleTransform: CGAffineTransform!
        let origin: CGPoint

        if(image!.size.width > image!.size.height) {
            let scaleRatio: CGFloat = self.cameraView.frame.height / image!.size.height
            scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleRatio, scaleRatio)

            origin = CGPointMake(-(image!.size.width - image!.size.height) / 2.0, 0)
        }else {
            let scaleRatio: CGFloat = self.cameraView.frame.width / image!.size.width
            scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleRatio, scaleRatio)

            origin = CGPointMake(0, -(image!.size.height - image!.size.width) / 2.0)
        }

        let size: CGSize = CGSizeMake(self.cameraView.frame.width, self.cameraView.frame.height)

        if (UIScreen.mainScreen().respondsToSelector(Selector("scale")) && UIScreen.mainScreen().scale >= 2.0) {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0.0)
        }else {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        }

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, scaleTransform)

        image!.drawAtPoint(origin)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        self.cameraView.hidden = true
        self.imageView.hidden = false
        self.imageView.image = newImage

                    print("newImage width \(newImage.size.width )")
                    print("newImage height \(newImage.size.height)")
    })
}
```

**NOTE:** Please do not bother the cameraManager instance if you are not using this library. The related code just simply took the image from shot so the image instance is the image taken by ios Camera which is output of AVFoundation.

*Aside Information -* However, I would recommend you to have a look to the CameraManager pod. It simplifies the AVFoundationUsage greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Swift 3 modification :

```
func takePhoto() {
    cameraManager.capturePictureWithCompletion({ (image, error) -> Void in
        let scaleTransform: CGAffineTransform!
        let origin: CGPoint

        if(image!.size.width > image!.size.height) {
            let scaleRatio: CGFloat = self.cameraView.frame.height / image!.size.height
            scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleRatio, y: scaleRatio)

            origin = CGPoint(x: -(image!.size.width - image!.size.height) / 2.0, y: 0)
        }else {
            let scaleRatio: CGFloat = self.cameraView.frame.width / image!.size.width
            scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleRatio, y: scaleRatio)

            origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y:  -(image!.size.height - image!.size.width) / 2.0)
        }

        let size: CGSize = CGSize(width: self.cameraView.frame.width, height: self.cameraView.frame.height)


        if (UIScreen.main.scale >= 2.0 && UIScreen.main.responds(to: #selector(NSDecimalNumberBehaviors.scale))) {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0.0)
        }else {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        }

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context!.concatenate(scaleTransform)

        image!.draw(at: origin)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        self.pushImageToForm(image: newImage!)
    })

}
```